# How to integrate killable processes/thread in Python GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, kill-process

Kind all, I'm really new to python and I'm facing a task which I can't completely grasp.

I've created an interface with Tkinter which should accomplish a couple of apparently easy feats.
By clicking a "Start" button two threads/processes will be started (each calling multiple subfunctions) which mainly read data from a serial port (one port per process, of course) and write them to file. 
The I/O actions are looped within a while loop with a very high counter to allow them to go onward almost indefinitely.

The "Stop" button should stop the acquisition and essentially it should:

1. Kill the read/write Thread
2. Close the file
3. Close the serial port

Unfortunately I still do not understand how to accomplish point 1, i.e.: how to create killable threads without killing the whole GUI. Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to choose whether you are going to use threads or processes.

I will not go too much into differences, google it ;) Anyway, here are some things to consider: it is much easier to establish communication between threads than betweeween processes; in Python, all threads will run on the same CPU core (see [Python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), but subprocesses may use multiple cores.

**Processes**

If you are using subprocesses, there are two ways: `subprocess.Popen` and `multiprocessing.Process`. With `Popen` you can run anything, whereas `Process` gives a simpler thread-like interface to running python code which is part of your project in a subprocess.

Both can be killed using `terminate` method.

See documentation for [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Of course, if you want a more graceful exit, you will want to send an "exit" message to the subprocess, rather than just terminate it, so that it gets a chance to do the clean-up. You could do that e.g. by writing to its stdin. The process should read from stdin and when it gets message "exit", it should do whatever you need before exiting.

**Threads**

For threads, you have to implement your own mechanism for stopping, rather than using something as violent as `process.terminate()`.

Usually, a thread runs in a loop and in that loop you check for a flag which says *stop*. Then you break from the loop.

I usually have something like this:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            # do something
            self._stop_event.wait(SLEEP_TIME)
        # clean-up before exit

    def stop(self, timeout):
        self._stop_event.set()
        self.join(timeout)
```

Of course, you need some exception handling etc, but this is the basic idea.

**EDIT: Answers to questions in comment**

`thread.start_new_thread(your_function)` starts a new thread, that is correct. On the other hand, module `threading` gives you a higher-level API which is much nicer.

With `threading` module, you can do the same with:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=your_function)
t.start()
```

or you can make your own class which inherits from `Thread` and put your functionality in the `run` method, as in the example above. Then, when user clicks the start button, you do:

```
t = MyThread()
t.start()
```

You should store the t variable somewhere. Exactly where depends on how you designed the rest of your application. I would probably have some object which hold all active threads in a list.

When user clicks stop, you should:

```
t.stop(some_reasonable_time_in_which_the_thread_should_stop)
```

After that, you can remove the `t` from your list, it is not usable any more.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! I think I'm missing the main point of threading then. In my case the function with the while loop is spawned in a thread by `thread.start_new_thread(function_with_while)`, but instead I should loop the **thread** rather than the function itself. Is that correct? And in this case, how do I pass to the thread the stop flag? The thread will spawn at "Start" button press, but the stop is handled by another Tkinter object (the "Stop" button). Is it enough to make the thread global?

Comment: thanks, but the point is that when the user clicks stop the thread should become aware that a stop flag has been raised and stop, otherwise keep acquiring on the serial port. There's no "reasonable time for stopping" because it should keep acquiring unless told otherwise. That's the part I find really hard and it does not allow me to insert "sleep" points in the acquisition step otherwise I will lose packages from  the port...

Comment: The timout argument for `stop` is optional. You can set it to `None`. See documentation for [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). If you implement your run method well, this will stop immediately. The reason to have a timeout is so that you can handle problems with a thread. E.g. if you have an error in `run` which causes it to never stop, calling `stop` (which calls `join`) will freeze the main thread. The timeout tells the function when to give up is the thread is not responding. What you do in that case is again up to you.

Comment: thanks, it's pretty clear, in fact that's exactly what's happening: I implemented my thread as a thread class (i.e.: `MyThread(threading.Thread)`) and defined a join attribute (is it called like that in Python?): timeout is none and the whole GUI freezes when I click the "Stop" button and stop the thread...

Comment: `Thread.join()` does not do much. It just means "*wait for this thread to finish*". It does not cause the thread to stop. You have to tell it to stop and then wait for it to stop. BTW, that is a good explanation why it takes `timeout` argument - the meaning is "*wait for this thread to finish, but don't wait longer than X seconds*"

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `subprocess.Popen()` to spawn child processes, then later you can use `Popen.terminate()` to terminate them.

Note that you could also do everything in a single Python thread, without subprocesses, if you want to.  It's perfectly possible to "multiplex" reading from multiple ports in a single event loop.